# Cannot initialize a peer connection, because of 'cyclical structure in JSON object'

Tags: react-native, webrtc, react-native-webrtc

I am trying to create a peer connection like this:

```js
const iceServers: RTCIceServer[] = data.iceServers.map((s) => {
  return {
    urls: [s.uri],
    username: s.username,
    credential: s.credential,
  };
});

const configuration: RTCConfiguration = {
  iceServers: iceServers,
};

const conn = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration); <-- here comes the error
```

But I get always an `cyclical structure in JSON object` error.

The same error occurs even if I am only using urls: ["stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302",..] without username and credential.

I am using expo, but the project is ejected and running using XCode.

How can I proceed can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure from which source `data` comes from, but you should validate that `s.uri`, `s.username` and `s.credential` are strings indeed. At least one of them seems to be an object instead.

Comment: The same error occurs even if I am only using `urls: ["stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302",..]` without username and credential.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new fresh project and it worked. The data which comes from backend was still the same or the way I created the peer connection. The problem could be probably a dependency version issue, since I used other versions for some packages but I am not sure.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).